# Regular Expression for whole numbers and integers?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to detect all integers and whole numbers (among a lot of other things) from a string. Here are the regular expressions I am currently using:

Whole numbers: `r"[0-9]+"`

Integers: `r"[+,-]?[0-9]+"`

Here are the issues:

1. The whole numbers regex is detecting negative numbers as well, which I cannot have. How do I solve this? If I use a space before at start of the regex I get only positive numbers, but then I get a space at the start of my output!
2. For whole numbers, I would like to detect positive numbers with the format `+[0-9]` but store them without the sign.
3. For integers, I would like to store any positive integer detected with the sign, irrespective if it is present in the original string.

Almost done now:
One last thing, I have a string that says "Add 10 and -15". I want to store the integers in a list. I do so using the findall(). While storing the numbers is it possible to store '10' as '+10'

Comment: Aren't "whole numbers" and "positive integers" the same thing? I'm not understanding how you would distinguish between them.

Comment: Whole numbers and integers are the same thing. Positive integers are natural numbers.

Comment: What do you want to match in the string `"1.0 and 1e7"`? Both are numbers (but considered `float`s by Python).

Comment: @Cairnarvon Oh, right. Though that doesn't seem to match the OP's usage (as in question #2)

Comment: Your third wish is impossible to fulfill with regex alone. Regexes can only match text that is already present in the string.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

For positive integers, use

```
r"(?<![-.])\b[0-9]+\b(?!\.[0-9])"
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?<![-.])   # Assert that the previous character isn't a minus sign or a dot.
\b          # Anchor the match to the start of a number.
[0-9]+      # Match a number.
\b          # Anchor the match to the end of the number.
(?!\.[0-9]) # Assert that no decimal part follows.
```

For signed/unsigned integers, use

```
r"[+-]?(?<!\.)\b[0-9]+\b(?!\.[0-9])"
```

The word boundaries `\b` are crucial to make sure that the entire number is matched.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The boundaries were extremely helpful.

Comment: Almost done now:
One last thing, I have a string that says "Add 10 and -15". I want to store the integers in a list. I do so using the findall(). While storing the numbers is it possible to store '10' as '+10'

Comment: As I mentioned in my comment to your question, that is impossible. Regexes can only match text that's already there, it can't add anything to the match. You'll need to do this programmatically.

Comment: This fails on something like `10.23`. I think you need to add the `.` check to the beginning too.

Comment: Checking for a single dot after the digits is problematic, isn't it? "Add 10 and 12. Then multiply the result with 17."

Comment: @DanielFischer: You're right - one could change the lookahead assertion to `(?!\.[0-9])` to allow these cases.

Answer (score 4):

You almost had it.

```
import re

regex = re.compile(r'(\d+)|([\+-]?\d+)')

s = "1 2 3 4 5 6 +1 +2 +3 -1 -2 -3 +654 -789 321"
for r in regex.findall(s):
    if r[0]:
        # whole (unsigned)
        print 'whole', r[0]
    elif r[1]:
        # a signed integer
        print 'signed', r[1]
```

Results:

```
>>> 
whole 1
whole 2
whole 3
whole 4
whole 5
whole 6
signed +1
signed +2
signed +3
signed -1
signed -2
signed -3
signed +654
signed -789
whole 321
```

Or, you could use "or" to get the actual result in a "nicer" way:

```
print [r[0] or r[1] for r in regex.findall(s)]
>>> 
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '+1', '+2', '+3', '-1', '-2', '-3', '+654', '-789', '321']
```

---

Edit:
As per your question " [is it possible to store '10' as '+10'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16774064/regular-expression-for-whole-numbers-and-integers/16774242?noredirect=1#comment24169334_16774242)  " :

```
import re

def _sign(num):
    if r[0]:
        return '+%s'%r[0]
    else:
        return r[1]

regex = re.compile(r'(\d+)|([\+-]?\d+)')
s = "1 2 3 4 5 6 +1 +2 +3 -1 -2 -3 +654 -789 321"      
print [_sign(r) for r in regex.findall(s)]
>>>
['+1', '+2', '+3', '+4', '+5', '+6', '+1', '+2', '+3', '-1', '-2', '-3', '+654', '-789', '+321']
```

Or in 1-line:

```
print ['+%s'%r[0] if r[0] else r[1] for r in regex.findall(s)]
>>> 
['+1', '+2', '+3', '+4', '+5', '+6', '+1', '+2', '+3', '-1', '-2', '-3', '+654', '-789', '+321']
```

Comment: Almost done now:
One last thing, I have a string that says "Add 10 and -15". I want to store the integers in a list. I do so using the findall(). While storing the numbers is it possible to store '10' as '+10'

Comment: Thanks I just needed to know if it could be done while extracting the regex and without using an explicit function. Thanks anyways!

Comment: You can see the last line of my answer is all in one line.