# Regex with integer and decimals and dot and sign

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to validate a string with following allowed conditions

string can be signed or unsigned numbers with dot(.). for example

10 or .3 or 1. or 1.1 or +5 or -5 or +.3 or -1. etc

below link is almost a close answer but fails on "+.3"
[Regular Expression for whole numbers and integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16774064/regular-expression-for-whole-numbers-and-integers)

```
"[+-]?(?<!\.)\b[0-9]+\b(?!\.[0-9])"
```

Comment: Please stick to one language tag; using 3 is tantamount to spamming disparate communities.

Comment: Looks like I got the solution [+-]?\d+(\.\d*)?|\.\d|[+-]?(\.\d)

Comment: related: [Extract float/double value](http://stackoverflow.com/q/385558/4279)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if you want to exclude strings like *000000.12* this would work I beleive `[+-]?(0|[1-9]\d*)?(\.[0-9]+)?`

Comment: This regex will capture only `+`, only `-` or even an empty string.

Comment: @0605002 Thanks, you are right. Here is the fixed version `[+-]?(((0|[1-9]\d*)(\.\d*)?)|(\.\d+))`

Comment: This one captures `'-0'` from `'-0123.45'`.

Answer (score 0):

One solution may be:

```
[+-]?(((\d+\.?)|(\.?\d+))\d*)
```

Here `[+-]?` checks for the optional sign at the beginning, `(\d+\.?)` and `(\.?\d+)` will catch digit followed by `.` or `.` followed by digits (and covers the cases that contain a `.`), and finally `\d*` takes care of the trailing digits, if there is any.