# Regex for unsigned integers. I am using flex

Tags: regex, apache-flex

I have tried the code given on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16774064/regular-expression-for-whole-numbers-and-integers) `(?<![-.])\b[0-9]+\b(?!\.[0-9])`, but flex shows:
Bad Character: <
Bad Character: !
Bad Character: [
...

Comment: Always suspect that lookarounds aren't supported when you get an error like that !

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Flex but from a rapid google search, it appears that flex uses `<` and `>` characters for match tokens.  Try escaping these characters with a back slash and see if that helps.

`<` →  `\<`

Comment: thanks Jason but I have already tried that, in addition it shows
`Bad Character: \\`

Comment: In some languages like C#, `(?<` has a special function within the context of a regex.  In C#s case, it "captures the matched subexpression into a named group", such as `(?< name > subexpression)`.  It's possible that the regex implementation of Flex has a similar construct that would make this regex be considered invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry all, but according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22326399/flex-seems-do-not-support-a-regex-lookahead-assertion-the-fast-lex-analyzer) answer flex doesn't support lookahead.
I think I should take this question down.